# How to set the maintenance window for elastic pool in Bicep script?

Tags: json, sql-server, azure-bicep, azure-elasticpool

I had no luck figuring out what to pass for "maintenanceConfigurationId" to set the maintenance window.

Here's the bicep:

```
resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2021-11-01' existing = {
  name: sqlServerName
}

resource sqlElasticPool 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticPools@2021-11-01' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  parent: sqlServer
  properties: {
    //maintenanceConfigurationId: maintenanceConfigurationId
  }
}
```

I tried both "System default" and "System default (5pm to 8am)". Both aren't recognized/accepted values for **maintenanceConfigurationId**.

Here's the parameter value:

```
    "sql_elastic_pools": [
      {
        "name": "sqlep-<redact>",
        "subscription": "sub-<redact>",
        "resource_group": "rg-<redact>",
        "location": "usgovvirginia",
        "server": "sql-<redact>",
        "compute_and_storage": "Standard-series Gen5 4 vCores 500 GB",
        "maintenance_window": "System default (5pm to 8am)",
        "tags": {
          "app": "Data Migration",
          "environment": "Non-Production",
          "description": "None"
        }
      }
    ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried both "System default" and "System default (5pm to 8am)". Both
> aren't recognized/accepted values for maintenanceConfigurationId.

Provide them in a Subscription-ResourceId format. Eg;

```
maintenanceConfigurationId: '/subscriptions/your-subscription-id/providers/Microsoft.Maintenance/publicMaintenanceConfigurations/SQL_Default'

maintenanceConfigurationId: '/subscriptions/your-subscription-id/providers/Microsoft.Maintenance/publicMaintenanceConfigurations/SQL_EastUS_DB_1'
```

You could also declare them as an existing resource and then reference them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.maintenance/2021-09-01-preview/publicmaintenanceconfigurations?pivots=deployment-language-bicep

Comment: you can also use this syntax: `subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Maintenance/publicMaintenanceConfigurations', 'SQL_Default')`